# C# polling to check for files and start a program

Tags: c#

Can someone provide me a sample code of c# polling which will look for files in a folder and if the files are there then execute a batch files. If the files are not there then check the folder every 30 minutes. Also once it finds all the files wait 10 minutes before starting the batch file.

Comment: Look at `FileSystemWatcher` class.

Comment: My manager wants me to use c# polling. He does't like FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Start by breaking the problem down into individual steps, and figure out how to do each step. You've basically just asked for sample code to do everything you're trying to do. You're not going to find that.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and describe the problems that you have. Reposting the same questions over and over is not likiley to illicit different answers than you already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polling is not good as it will load your CPU up to 100%.

Use `FileSystemWatcher` Class instead.

Here is an  [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

**EDIT:**  Well, if you want to make your manager happy, you can do following :)

```
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
     {
        while(true)
        {
          if(File.Exists("file.txt") && File.Exists("file2.txt"))
          {
            //your action here
          }
          else
          {
            Thread.Sleep(1000*60*30);
          }
        }
     });
```

Comment: If only there was such as thing as a `Timer`...

Comment: @JonB this solution is to make the manager happy and I really believe it's more simple for the beginner :)

Comment: Using a timer is very beginner friendly.

Comment: @JonB ... if you explain to him that there are at least 3 of them and what is their behavior difference :)